# What types of wire should I use to pull out from a Test Point while using Cheap Logic Analyser or Oscilloscope?

Tags: wire

The only purpose to ask this question is I use single/multi-core thin wires that snap of in few days. I don't want that. Is there something that doesn't break?

Or some other tricks/connectors or anything else because I really don't know what should I use. It would be more helpful if it is economic solution.

Comment: Well, everything breaks if you try hard enough. But I would suggest stranded wire if you need it to flex a lot. Test points are usually intended to just be probed directly, though.

Comment: Could you describe better (or provide a photo) of exactly what you are asking about? Is the test point a physical testpoint that you can glomp a hook probe onto? A pad that accepts a pogo pin in a test fixture? A fly wire you have just soldered to some particular point of interest? Why are you leaving the circuit connected and handling it for days?

Comment: @spehro A fly wire soldered at my point of interest. Umm.. I didn't get you last question. Shouldn't I be doing it? I am working with SPI Protocol right now to interface an SD Card so I prefer keeping it connected as long as I am working on it.

Comment: @Felthry I checked out stranded wire. That is what we call multi-core wire. I think I should show what kinda wire I am using. I'll do the needed soon

Answer (score 1):

I have found solid wires (eg. wire-wrap wires) to be acceptable for this purpose. Also light (eg. AWG 28) PTFE-insulated stranded wires. The key thing to keep them from breaking off is to **strain relieve the wires so they don't bend at the joint every time you handle the board**. If you can epoxy or hot-glue a connector or strain relief to the board or to something the board is mounted to you can eliminate those problems. Sometimes it's enough to just wrap the wires through a (preferably unplated in case the insulation gets damaged) mounting hole on their way off the board. Or embed them in a blob of hot glue.

I also usually insist that there should be at least one real hook/alligator clip compatible test point on the board - connected to ground. After that, supply rails, and after that signals such as the ones you mention.

If the board has room the connections can be brought out to a header (for small quantity situations or where a test fixture will not be available) and the header simply not populated for boards populated after the initial boards are debugged. The wire-to-board connector pairs usually have good strain relief characteristics. You can get 2.54mm, 2.0mm and finer pitch connectors easily and inexpensively. The tool to crimp the contacts properly can be a bit pricey.